# How many contiguous "strings" can you find in a set of strings?

Tags: code-challenge, string, printable-ascii

Consider the set of 16-character strings containing only the [95 printable ASCII characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters). There are 95<sup>16</sup> ≈ [4.4×10<sup>31</sup>](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=95%5E16) such strings.

Imagine these strings are put into a list and sorted [lexicographically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) (which is the way most languages will sort a list of strings). What is the largest **contiguous** slice of this list you can find such that every string is a valid program in your programming language of choice whose output is the sole word `string`?

All output should go to the same place for all programs; use stdout or a similar alternative.
An optional trailing newline may be a part of the output, but otherwise nothing besides `string` should be printed for any of your 16-character programs. There is no input and all programs should run without erroring. The program **does not** have to terminate.

The list of length 16 strings does not "loop-around" from `~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~` to                  (16 spaces).

Give your starting string and ending string and explain why every program-string that's in between them lexicographically outputs `string`.

The submission with the largest slice wins.

Comment: Is it my imagination or is this challenge just "find the language that prints a string literal and can throw away the most additional characters"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [///](http://esolangs.org/wiki////), 6634204313747905 > 95<sup>8</sup>

From

```
string/.~~~~~/0
```

to

```
string/0     /.~
```

This relies on the program not being required to terminate. I started from a core-range of 95<sup>8</sup> much like the other solutions, from

```
string//
```

to

```
string//~~~~~~~~
```

However, in this case, `//` is not a comment. In **///** everything that's not a slash is just printed (hence this always prints `string` before doing anything else). A slash then starts a substitution pattern of the form `/pattern/replacement/`. If only one or two `/` are found, then the program simply terminates. However, the above range obviously also includes strings with three or more slashes. The trick here is that the pattern to be searched for is empty, and substitutions are performed iteratively until the pattern cannot be found any more. Since the empty string can *always* be found, this substitution never terminates, and hence the program never gets around to print anything after the initial `string`.

But since this doesn't rely on `//` being a comment, we can actually go a bit further! E.g. the previous and next string around this range, respectively, are:

```
string/.~~~~~~~~
string/0
```

These still don't contain a full substitution instruction so they also only print `string` and then terminate. Let's see how far we can go! I'll focus on the upper end of the range (the lower end works analogously). What if we get another `/`? The first time this happens is

```
string/0       /
```

But that's still not a valid replacement pattern, so all is well. It looks like we need three slashes to break the magic. The first time we get three slashes is at

```
string/0      //
```

What now? Well, the pattern to be searched for is `0` (and a bunch of spaces), to be replaced with an empty string. That pattern is never found, so the substitution completes immediately. But luckily, there is nothing to print *afterwards* in the source code, so the result is *still* only `string`. Neat. :)

So we need a valid substitution instruction *and* more source code afterwards to not print `string`:

```
string/0     //
```

And this is indeed the first code that doesn't work to spec, as it prints `string` followed by a space. So the last code that works is

```
string/0     /.~
```

We can apply the same argument to the beginning of the range, the last failing code being

```
string/.~~~~~//~
```

such that the first code that works is

```
string/.~~~~~/0
```

Answer (score 3):

## [pyexpander](http://pyexpander.sourceforge.net/): 95^8 = 6634204312890625

```
string$#
```

to

```
string$#~~~~~~~~
```

Wow, it took forever to find the language I was looking for: one that outputs most source literals untouched and has a rest-of-line comment delimiter. This is still not theoretically optimal, as it's possible that another language like this exists, but with a one-character comment delimiter. However, I couldn't find one.

Comment: This is almost 100 times better than the other answers. xD

Answer (score 2):

### GolfScript: 95^7 = 69833729609375

```
"string"#
```

to

```
"string"#~~~~~~~
```

Everything from the `#` is a comment; the literal string is echoed at the end of execution.

Comment: I think your score is actually a bit higher. The code before your first one is `"string""~~~~~~~` and as far as I know and unmatched `"` acts like a "supercomment" just as an unmatched `}` does. So I think your earliest valid code is `"string""~~~~~~#`.

Comment: @MartinBüttner, no, the parser complains "Unterminated string meets end of file".

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 95^7 = 69833729609375

```
string<?#
```

followed by arbitrary characters.

Comment: +1 for using my pet language. Golfing in PHP is a real challenge :)

Answer (score 1):

## Microscript, 95^6=735091890625

`"gnirts"ah` (padded to 16 chars with trailing spaces) through `"gnirts"ah~~~~~~`

Answer (score 0):

### Windows Powershell: 95^7 = 69833729609375

```
"string"#
```

to

```
"string"#~~~~~~~
```

All characters from the # and following are part of a comment.

Same as @PeterTaylor's GolfScript answer